# Libmpeg2 decoding errors

Tags: c, debugging, video-processing

When I try to decode videos using libmpeg2 I get errors 31c and 301, I cannot find them in code and output video is broken.

I have downloaded libmpeg2 from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libmpeg2/). To reproduce this on x86, a build directory was made and ran cmake and then make.

For test video I downloaded [this](https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mpeg/sample_1280x720.mpeg) and for config file I used:

```
--input sample.mpeg
--output out.yuv
--save_output 1
--num_frames -1
--chroma_format YUV_420P
--share_display_buf 0
--max_wd 1280
--max_ht 720
--num_cores 1
--loopback 0
--display 0
--fps 30
--arch X86_GENERIC
--soc GENERIC
```

When I run `./mpeg2dec x86_test.cfg` I get this output:

```
FrameNum:    1 TimeTaken(microsec):    400 AvgTime:    400 PeakAvgTimeMax:     50 Output:  0 NumBytes:   1993 
FrameNum:    2 TimeTaken(microsec):   1942 AvgTime:   1171 PeakAvgTimeMax:    292 Output:  0 NumBytes: 143360 
FrameNum:    3 TimeTaken(microsec):   3644 AvgTime:   1995 PeakAvgTimeMax:    748 Output:  1 NumBytes: 278528 
FrameNum:    4 TimeTaken(microsec):   2374 AvgTime:   2090 PeakAvgTimeMax:   1045 Output:  1 NumBytes: 147456 
FrameNum:    5 TimeTaken(microsec):   3193 AvgTime:   2310 PeakAvgTimeMax:   1444 Output:  1 NumBytes:  77824 
FrameNum:    6 TimeTaken(microsec):   1274 AvgTime:   2137 PeakAvgTimeMax:   1603 Output:  1 NumBytes:  36864 
FrameNum:    7 TimeTaken(microsec):    788 AvgTime:   1945 PeakAvgTimeMax:   1701 Output:  0 NumBytes:  12291 
Error in video Frame decode : ret 1 Error 301
FrameNum:    8 TimeTaken(microsec):    996 AvgTime:   1826 PeakAvgTimeMax:   1826 Output:  1 NumBytes:  18429 
FrameNum:    9 TimeTaken(microsec):   3218 AvgTime:   1981 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2178 Output:  1 NumBytes:  14336 
FrameNum:   10 TimeTaken(microsec):   1688 AvgTime:   1951 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2178 Output:  1 NumBytes:   4096 
FrameNum:   11 TimeTaken(microsec):   1436 AvgTime:   1904 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2178 Output:  1 NumBytes:   6144

***

FrameNum:  367 TimeTaken(microsec):   1570 AvgTime:   1549 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2218 Output:  1 NumBytes:   6132 
FrameNum:  368 TimeTaken(microsec):   1666 AvgTime:   1549 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2218 Output:  1 NumBytes:   6144 
FrameNum:  369 TimeTaken(microsec):   1091 AvgTime:   1548 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2218 Output:  1 NumBytes:   4096 
FrameNum:  370 TimeTaken(microsec):    784 AvgTime:   1546 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2218 Output:  0 NumBytes:  11212 
Error in video Frame decode : ret 1 Error 31c
FrameNum:  371 TimeTaken(microsec):   1127 AvgTime:   1545 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2218 Output:  1 NumBytes:   1076 
FrameNum:  372 TimeTaken(microsec):    634 AvgTime:   1542 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2218 Output:  1 NumBytes:   6144 
FrameNum:  373 TimeTaken(microsec):   1046 AvgTime:   1541 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2218 Output:  1 NumBytes:   4096 
FrameNum:  374 TimeTaken(microsec):   2412 AvgTime:   1543 PeakAvgTimeMax:   2218 Output:  1 NumBytes:  43008 

***

Summary
Input filename                  : sample.mpeg
Output Width                    : 1280
Output Height                   : 720 
Bitrate @ 30 fps(mbps)          : 2.12  
Average decode time(micro sec)  : 1497  
Avg Peak decode time( 8 frames) : 5334  
FPS achieved (with format conv) : 667.96
```

So I get these two error which I cannot find in code, the decoded video is broken and summary numbers aren't correct. I play .yuv file using `ffplay -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format yuv420p -f rawvideo out.yuv`.

Answer (score 1):

The error codes are printed in hexadecimal and the error codes 0x301 and 0x31c are the values of enumerated constants `IMPEG2D_UNKNOWN_ERROR` and `IMPEG2D_INVALID_PIC_TYPE` defined in "decoder/impeg2d.h":

```
typedef enum
{

    IMPEG2D_UNKNOWN_ERROR = IVD_DUMMY_ELEMENT_FOR_CODEC_EXTENSIONS + 1,
```

More constants follow …
This is the 28th constant in the enumeration:

```
    IMPEG2D_INVALID_PIC_TYPE,
```

More constants follow …

```
} IMPEG2D_ERROR_CODES_T;
```

`IVD_DUMMY_ELEMENT_FOR_CODEC_EXTENSIONS` is an enumerated constant defined in "decoder/ivd.h":

```
    IVD_DUMMY_ELEMENT_FOR_CODEC_EXTENSIONS      = 0x300,
```

So:

- `IMPEG2D_UNKNOWN_ERROR` = 0x301
- `IMPEG2D_INVALID_PIC_TYPE` = 0x31c